# Less than date value in Stored Procedures is not working

Tags: mysql

I have couple of tables

1. Movements
2. Entries

and want to get the stock balance of items up to a given date. So I created queries and INNER JOINED to make a single table so it is easy to get the balance. This program is saved in a SP called

```
StblAsAt(IN RefDate DATE,IN Store VARCHAR,OUT @STBL DOUBLE)
```

However when I user the date format in the body as appears in the following line it works fine.

```
purchaseinvoice.invoiceDate<='2021-08-30'
```

But when it is changed to use the parameter, it returns zero (0). No matter what date I pass.

This is my code as it is in Stored Procedure

```
    BEGIN
SELECT  (Purchase+SalesReturns+TransferIn)-(PurchaseReturns+Sales+TransferOut) INTO @STBL FROM(
    SELECT COALESCE(P.Purchase,0)AS 'Purchase',
    COALESCE(Sr.SalesReturn,0)AS 'SalesReturns',
    COALESCE(Ti.TransferIn,0)AS 'TransferIn',
    COALESCE(Pr.PurchaseReturns,0)AS 'PurchaseReturns',
    COALESCE(S.Sales,0) AS 'Sales',
    COALESCE(Tout.TransferOut,0)AS 'TransferOut'
    FROM(
    (SELECT 
        'OTHRMA1032' AS 'Item',
        SUM(movement.itemQty) AS 'Purchase'
    FROM movement 
    WHERE 
        movement.movementType=0 AND
        movement.entryDate<=DATE_FORMAT(@RefDate,'%Y-%m-%d')AND   #Tried @RefDate and it fails
        movement.itemId='OTHRMA1032' AND
        movement.reference2 IN(
            SELECT purchaseinvoice.GRNId 
            FROM purchaseinvoice
            WHERE 
                purchaseinvoice.invoiceDate<=DATE_FORMAT(@RefDate,'%Y-%m-%d') AND
                purchaseinvoice.inwardStore='Main store'
            ))P
```

(Didn't include all queries as it would make the post junk)

This is how I call the procedure from MySql

CALL StblAsAt('2021-08-30','Main store',@STBL);

Whenever the parameter is used, it returns zero and when the date is typed in, it returns the correct value.

Comment: Why are you using `date_format()` function to compare dates? That will return a `string` and you will be comparing `purchasinginvoice.invoiceDate` (I assume a `date` field type) to a string. Just `WHERE purchasinginvoice.invoiceDate <= @RefDate` should suffice.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I Tried this @RefDate and the result was same. Surprisingly it is now working without @. I tried just "RefDate" and it worked but don't know why.